# Incrementing in a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried many sqls to get this working, but I just cant seem to get it working.

What I want to do:

I have two columns in a table, column 1 contains distinct values, where some of them have the same value in column 2. I want to have a column 3 with incremented number that are counting these.

Hard to explain, it might be easier to show you:

```
1. Column1 | Column2 | Column3
2.  a_______1__________1
3.  b_______1__________2
4.  c_______1__________3
5.  d_______1__________4
6.  e_______2__________1
7.  f_______2__________2
8.  g_______2__________3
9.  h_______3__________1
10. i_______3__________2
11. j_______4__________1
12. k_______4__________2
13. l_______4__________3
```

I want to:
For each value in column 1, to count in column 3 until column 2 goes to another value.

Can someone please help? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to assign an increasing value for each row with the same `column2`:

```
select  *
,       row_number() over (partition by column2 order by column1) as Column3
from    YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Tablename: @Data

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, COUNT(t2.col2) AS sum
FROM @Data t1
INNER JOIN @Data t2 ON t1.col1 >= t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2
ORDER BY t1.col1
```

This is sql-server syntax but logic should be the same for oracle.

Comment: Thanks Pieter B! That did just what I was looking for :)